# When is the smallest point on a hull a convex combination of the smallest vertices?

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, euclidean-geometry, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

Let $x_1, \dots, x_n\in\mathbb{R}^d$ be a finite set of points and denote the convex hull by $H$. Assume that $0\not\in H$ and also that each $x_i$ is an extreme point, meaning that it cannot be expressed as a convex combination of the remaining points.

Consider the smallest element in the hull

$$x^* := \arg\min_{x \in H} |x|^2$$

By Caratheodory's theorem, $x^*$ can be expressed as a convex combination of $d$ of the points $x_1, \dots, x_n$. **Is it true that $x^*$ is a convex combination of the $d$ *smallest* points ?**

While this seems like a plausible hypothesis, the answer is no. For example, consider $x_1=(2,0), x_2=(0,1)$ and
$x_3=(2/5+\epsilon,4/5+\epsilon)$. It's easy to see that $x^*=(2/5,4/5)$, but $x^*$ cannot be written as a convex combination of $x_2$ and $x_3$.

However in this counterexample, the points are nearly co-linear. So it seems possible that the statement could be true assuming that the points are sufficiently "generic." So I will reformulate the original question:

**Is there a sufficient condition which implies that $x^*$ is a convex combination of the $d$ smallest points? If not, is it at least true with high probability under reasonable sampling assumptions?**

Comment: What is wrong with allowing $x_3$ to have coefficient $0$?

Comment: indeed let me quote Caratheodory's theorem :

"if a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ lies in the convex hull of a set $P$, then $x$ can be written as a combination of _at most_ $d + 1$ points of $P$"

Comment: @Olivier Roche yes of course $x_3$ could have a zero coefficient, but then that would be a convex combination of $d+1$ points. As per the question, I only want to allow up to $d$ points. I have also clarified the example slightly.

Comment: (Note that $x^*$ must lie on the boundary. I am thus applying C's theorem to the face of the boundary containing $x^*$, which is why it is $d$ rather than $d+1$).

Comment: @MikeHawk If I understand it correctly, this is equivalent to the distance from $O$ to $H$ being the same as the distance from $O$ to the convex hull of the $d$ points nearest to the origin. I don't see offhand why that would be the case in general. Suppose you start with those $d$ points then add the $(d+1)^{th}$ point, farther away than all others. Whether the distance from $O$ to the new hull changes or not seems to depend on which side of a hyperplane the new point gets chosen.

Answer (score 1):

> **Is it true that $x^∗$ is a convex combination of the d smallest points ?**

**Not in general**, consider the following example in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ :
Consider the points $A(0; 1), B(6; 0), C(2; 2)$ and $S := \{A; B; C\} $ . The convex hull $H$ of $S$ is the triangle $ABC$. The two points in $S$ that are closest to $O$ are $A$ and $C$.
Clearly, $x^*$ lies on the line segment $[AB]$ and not on the line segment $[AC]$.

> **Is there a sufficient condition which implies that x∗ is a convex combination of the d smallest points? If not, is it at least true with high probability under reasonable sampling assumptions?**

No reasonable assumption I'm affraid : the counter-example above hints that you should *at least* require the dimension of $H$ to be ***strictly less than $d$***.